# No recibo $_SESSION["userId"] que envío como API de PHP hacia JavaScript

Tags: php, ajax, api, autenticación, fetch

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación web sencilla para practicar, son listas de tareas en las que puedes iniciar sesión. La aplicación está hecha con React.js (next.js) en el frontend que lee una API hecha con php y tuve problemas al momento de mostrar las listas correspondientes de cada usuario. En la API php hice un simple select con eloquent para mostrar las listas correspondientes según el ID del usuario, la API suelta información de esta manera:

`$sessionUserId= $_SESSION["userId"] ?? null;
$read = new ReadController();
$listas = $read->ReadAction($sessionUserId);
$data = array(
    "title" => "Listas",
    "listas" => $listas,
    "session" => $sessionUserId 
);
echo json_encode($data);`
La variable `$_SESSION["userId"]` se define cuando te logueas y haciendole un `var_dumb()`está correctamente definida. 
la clase ReadController es la siguiente:

```
class ReadController {
public function ReadAction($sessionUserId){
    $listas = Lista::
    select("id","title", "description", "user_id")
    ->where("user_id", $sessionUserId)
    ->where("active", 1)
    ->get();
    return $listas;
}
```

El punto es que la API funciona correctamente y al hacer login se ve lo siguiente

```
{
"title":"Listas",
"listas":[
   {
    "id":4,
    "title":"Comprar Leche",
    "description":"",
    "user_id":5
   },
   {
    "id":5,
    "title":"Bañar al perro",
    "description":"",
    "user_id":5
   }
 ],
 "session":5
}
```

Es decir todo es correcto, me muestra las listas únicamente del usuario número 5.

El punto es que en el lado del FrontEnd no lee los datos y sale todo en blanco, sin embargo si "harcodeo" esta función de esta manera

```
$listas = $read->ReadAction(5)
```

(En vez de la variable `$sessionUserId`) entonces todo funciona correctamente, esta es la función que lee los datos en el lado del FrontEnd:

```
`static async getInitialProps(){

let req = await fetch(Front_data.server.url,{

  credentials: "include"  
})
let data = await req.json();
return {data}
```

}`

Está hecho con Next.js pero eso no influye tanto porque probé con una simple vanilla.js y tampoco lee los datos.

para ejemplificar, notan también que hay una variable en el JSON de la API que dice `"session"` ? pues si lo intento leer en el frontEnd me sale un "null" y si hago un `var_dumb()` de esa misma variable en php lo lee como un simple `int(#numero)`.
Voy bastante tiempo con este problema, alguien ayúdeme porfavor, si alguien quiere leer todo el código está aquí [repositorio github del proyecto](https://github.com/SuperKleber/listas-php-practica)

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entendí bien si tu problema es con la variable de sesión. Sugiero que hagas un var_dump completo de esa variable para ver lo que hay en ella: `var_dump($_SESSION);`, puede que la clave venga así `user_id` en la variable de sesión, o que esté vacía la variable, eso es fácil de saber probando la variable de sesión completa. Y si puedes explica mejor el problema, porque yo al menos no llego a comprender bien cuál es la lógica que sigues no qué haces realmente o intentas hacer.

Comment: Estas haciendo uso de una API Rest? Debes recordar que son "statelees" , es decir que no tienen estados. No existen las variables de session. Por lo tanto tu $_SESSION["userId"] siempre va a ser null.

Comment: La variable `$_SESSION["userId"]` se define cuando haces login además al hacer un `var_dumb()` todo está correcto, por si acaso también puse el `session_start()`. Como digo, en la API todo funciona correctamente, como pueden observar en el JSON, peroel FrontEnd no quiere leerlo.

Comment: No sabemos qué quieres decir con *todo está correcto*. Quisiera que muestres el resultado del `var_dump`, porque puede que todo esté correcto, pero que haya alguna incoherencia en tu código. Aquí ver la variable de sesión es esencial para comprobar los datos y el código.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que cuando un usuario hace LOGIN, y el ID de este usuario es por ejemplo "5", el resultado de `var_dumb($_SESSION["userId"])` es `int(5)`, y en la API muestra las listas de tareas que corresponden al usuario que tiene el ID "5", como debe ser, si se fija en el JSON de la API, cada objeto del array "listas" tiene una variable que es "user_id" que indica a qué usuario pertenece esa lista en específico, también hayuna variable en la API que dice "session" y como puede observar es la ID del usuario, en este ejemplo vale "5", pero la intentar leer eso  con JS sale `null`.

Comment: Talvez también es de aclarar que la API funciona en una dirección diferente al frontEnd, la API está en `http://localhost/listas-php-react/server/index.php` y el FrontEnd en `http://localhost:3000/`